# How can I poison myself?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got a weak poison that has healing properties! I play with the Requiem mod so any healing source is acceptable. But I can't find a way to poison myself. I tried to shoot an arrow upwards (and use a shield and high armor class of course), but it won't hit me.

Maybe poison some deployable weak trap? Or convert the poison into a potion, but how?

I'll accept console commands that can do the trick!

Comment: You can always just go into some random dungeon, and look for some insects that poison you. Or are you literally looking for a poison potion?

Comment: I want to be able to use the healing properties of the poison!

Comment: omg... ppl are voting down and they dont even explain why...

Comment: @AquariusPower I did not downvote you, but a likely reason for downvotes is that the original version of the question was a bit difficult to read.

Comment: oh ok thx (it just received several edits :))

Comment: Another reason to downvote: the question deals with a problem that nobody else is likely to experience, like "how do I kill Alduin armed only with a head of lettuce, a piece of yarn and a lesser soul gem".

Comment: haha ok, I just giveup, read more about downvotes [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?rq=1), just harden yourself and dont care :)

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable question. This *is* a role-playing game, after all. Who are we to judge if people want to play as characters that poison themselves? =) Also, OP mentioned that he is using a mod, which makes it advantageous to poison one's self. As a side note, in TES IV: Oblivion, [you *can* poison yourself](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Poisoned_Apple) without resorting to workarounds like in Skyrim.

Comment: @kotekzot The answer to that is simple and trivial: invoke Sheogorath's help, and he'll make it rain burning dogs.

Comment: @galacticninja lol! cool! maybe a mod that add poisoned apples to the game lol, bandits could be lured to it after placing it, AND we could simply eat it :>

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can make out the only way to do this is to apply the poison to a weapon, and then pickpocket that weapon *into* someone else's inventory, then provoke them to attack you.

Comment: I read it elsewhere too, but then, the attacker wont stop :), I tried to change ownership of the arrow but didnt work too..

Comment: @AquariusPower Give it to someone you can easily kill once you've been poisoned then.

Comment: but the poison has healing properties, even the first hit (with Requiem mod) may nullify the poison potion, the effect and the desired result :)